# HTML / JavaScript: All images click open in new page

Tags: html, image, png, jpeg, thumbnails

I have a LAMP-driven database that generates a lot of php-driven web pages with images on them.  The images are reduced to thumbnails on the main pages.

I would like to create an HTML / JavaScript / PHP method or code that basically makes EVERY image clickable, and if it is clicked, the image is open in a "_blank" window by itself, at full size.  I do not want to have to create this code for every possible image, but can do so if necessary.

This would be the equivalent action in Chrome of right-clicking an image, and choosing "Open Image in New Tab"

Any way to do this?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please post your code here, if you tried.

Answer (score 0):

In php, you can do something like this.

```
<?php
$images = Array('one.png','two.png','three.png');
foreach ($images as $k=>$v) {
    echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.$v.'">';
    echo '<img class="image" src="'.$v.'" />';
    echo '</a>';
}
?>
```